# Geometrical Interpretation of minimizer inequality in Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

I was reading Hilbert space chapter In that I came across following. I can follow proof given in book.But I wanted to know what is geometric meaning of

### $$\langle f-u,v-u \rangle \leq 0,\forall v\in K$$

[image]

[image]

Also there is remark given below proof.In that author says $f:[0,1]\to R$ achieves minimum at 0 then $f'(0)\leq 0$ but it should be $f'(0)\geq 0$ also $f'(1)\leq 0$ but auther says $f'(1)=1$ I do not understand why?

Please, anyone, help me understand better.

Thanking you

Comment: It means that the arrow from $u$ to $f$ points in one direction and the arrow from any $u$ to any $v$ in $K$ points in the other direction. More precisely, if you project the arrow from $u$ to $v$ onto the line passing through $f$ and $u$, then the projection points in the opposite direction as the arrow from $u$ to $f$.

Comment: Regarding the remark: I agree that it doesn't seem to make sense as presented; we would probably need a bit more context to make sense of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your primary question: note that $\cos^{-1}(\langle f-u,v - u \rangle)$ is the angle between $f-u$ and $v - u$.  Stating that $\langle f-u,v - u \rangle\leq 0$ for all $v$ is equivalent to stating that the angle between $f-u$ and $v - u$ is always either right or obtuse.

To get a feeling for **why** this should be the case, I would suggest that you consider the simple example of 
$$
H = \Bbb R^2, \quad f = (2,0), \quad K = \{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}.
$$
In this case, we find that $u = (1,0)$. You should find $f$ and $K$ easy enough to draw.  Choose a random $v$ (or several), and consider what the vectors $f-u,v-u$ look like.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir. Dear Sir Remark is form Heime Brezis Page 134.Please help me about remark.

Comment: You're welcome.  I do not have the text, and even if I did I don't have the inclination to flip through the text right now.  I suggest that you post a new question for help with the remark.

Comment: Ok Sir I will post new question